# Want ActionBar's Up to mimic Back functionality, but have no way to ping it & menu layout doesn't reflect what I actually see

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

There are a few things I want to do, but I don't know if I did this right.

I simply created an Activity and declared its `android:parentActivityName` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When I click on an item in my ListView from my first fragment in my ViewPager, it takes me to that activity. When I press the `Back` button on my phone, it takes me back to the exact state that the Fragment and the ViewPager were in. However, when I press the `Up` button in my ActionBar, I am taken back to the Fragment and ActionBar but it seems to reload everything. I have found answers for applying the Back functionality to the Up button, but for some reason I can't reference the Up button in anyway.

When I view my menu file corresponding to the top, all I see is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.unlock.gate.CommentsActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

This is perplexing because I don't even see the three vertical dots representing the Settings but see the Up button. How do I alleviate this issue? Also, the label for this Activity is `Comments`. When I press the `Up button`, it seems to include the label in the highlighting. I would like these separated such that the Up button is by itself and the Label just sits there without being manipulated with the button.

Comment: I don't want to override it. I want to use `onBackPressed()` when the Up button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onMenuItemPressed(MenuItem item){
  switch(item.getId)
  {
    case android.R.id.home :
         onBackPressed();
         ....
         return;
    ...
  }
}
```

You can override up button pressed like this.

Comment: Ah, I kept trying to do this with `R.id.home` instead of `android.R.id.home`, which aren't the same! Is there any way to alleviate the other concerns I had?

Comment: Maybe this can be another option. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html